# Jquery Dynatree plugin - how to get children of a given node

Tags: jquery, dynatree

I looked through documentation and there seems to be no way to get an
array of children of a given node...

something like

```
 if (parentNode.hasChildren() == true) {
        alert('yay');

        if (parentNode.children == null) {
            alert('what the???');
        }
 }
```

this code will output 'yay', (i use a node that has children) but
parentNode.children is null because 'what the??' is also being output....

Is there any way to get an array of children of a particular node?

In the case above, i would expect the parentNode to have an array of children, but there seems to be no way to get the children, only add and remove them.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `parentNode.childList`

Comment: thanks! interestingly enough, it's not mentioned in the documentation at all:) unless I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
parentNode.children()
```

[jQuery children API](http://api.jquery.com/children/)